# Show sticky blog post on homepage

Tags: homepage, sticky-post

Is there a bit of PHP I can use to grab the sticky blog post (there will only ever be one) to drop into my homepage template file?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried a custom [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for sticky posts? Please edit your question to include your "homepage template", and whatever code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

[Straight out of the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$query = new WP_Query( 'p=' . $sticky[0] );
```